# Why there are no quotes when using dictionary based string formatting in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I may have a silly question:

```
x = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
print "%(a)s" % x   # works fine
print "%('a')s" % x  # failed
```

Could someone tell me why?

Comment: That's just the way the syntax works, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations): *"Mapping key (optional), consisting of a parenthesised sequence of characters (for example, `(somename)`)."*

Comment: Also % formatting is pretty much deprecated in favour of `str.format()`; there are many pitfalls with % formatting that are avoided by `str.format` that is now available in 99.5 % of python installations (2.6 +)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: %formatting is not deprecated, and it won't be deprecated in the neat future.  Moreover. unfortunately there are still loads of environments out there on older versions of Python.  (I don't have any actual numbers.  Do you, or was that just a guess?

Comment: `str.format` appeared in Python 2.6 and is preferred in 3.0 over the old `%` syntax. In my opinion absolutely no newbie needs to support <= 2.5 specifically, its installed base has dropped way beyond 3+, and being used mainly for maintenance-only projects. Though this is just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%(a)s` retrieves the value for the existing `a` key from `x`.

`%('a')s` attempts to get the value for non-existent `'a'` key (with quotes) and that causes the error to appear.

Simple code example:

```
>>> x = {"'a'": 'a within quotes', 'a': 'no quotes'}
>>> "%('a')s" % x
'a within quotes'
>>> "%(a)s" % x
'no quotes'
```

Comment: it seems the x in "%(x)s" has to be a literal and cannot to be a variable. If I want a variable how I should implement it? Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be a variable. It refers to a dictionary key. If you have the key in variable, you can do `"%(" + var + ")s"`, however easier to just change the dictionary used for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It is because it is searching for the key including `'a'` which is not defined on your query.